# How to write angular unit test for function and switch case

Tags: angular, unit-testing

```
extractValue(exemptionLevel: string, exemptionValue: any): string {
switch(exemptionLevel) {
  case "C": return exemptionValue.isoCountryCode.toString();
  case "R": return exemptionValue.districtNumber.toString();
  case "D": return exemptionValue.divisionCode.toString();
  case "T": return exemptionValue.terminalNumber.toString();
}
```

}

i tried below

```
it('expected value extractValue() c', () => {
component.extractValue('C','isoCountry');
expect('C').toEqual('isoCountry')

// expect(component.extractValue(expectedLevel[0], exemptionValue.isoCountryCode)).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

});

it showing error TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a string parameter to the function and you are expecting to access its `isoCountryCode` property, which will always be undefined. You have to provide the tested function with `exemptionValue` mock.

```typescript
it('expected value extractValue() c', () => {
  const isoCountryMockResult = 'someResult';
  const exemptionValue = { isoCountryCode: isoCountryMockResult } // define your mock
  component.extractValue('C', exemptionValue);
  expect('C').toEqual(isoCountryMockResult)
}
```

This should work, but you have to adjust it to your needs

Comment: working fine . thankyou dallows

Comment: You should accept the answer then

Comment: i accepted.. Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: How to write testcase subscribe inside constructor
`
constructor(private exemptionService:ExemptionService){
    this.exemptionService.getGlobalExemptionReasons().subscribe(reason => this.reason = reason);
}`